# Is Apex Managed Sharing the Best Option for my org?

Tags: apex-managed-sharing

In my org have customer community plus licenses which are role based. If I have multiple accounts with multiple users in this org I need to set up specific sharing rules to share records between each role since users in roles cannot see each others records. If I have 10 specific sharing rules for 10 objects I need to re-create them anytime I add another account and users for that account. I need a simpler/easier way to do this. For example, if I have account ABC and 2 users assigned to a role I need to create a sharing rule that user 1 can see user 2s records and vice versa. When I go to add another account I need to set up the same sharing rule for the new roles. This will become unmanageable. I cannot convert to customer community licenses because I need the reporting capabilities. Has anyone ever experienced an issue like this?

Comment: I created a trigger in order to do this, and can help if you decide to take this route.